# Confusing field assignment in a generic classes inherited from a generic interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, entity, dbcontext

I am reading about the **Repository Pattern** design. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615499/Models-POCO-Entity-Framework-and-Data-Patterns][1]) is really good but I don't understand a few things inside a constructor.

In this code:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> GetAll(); 
        T GetById(int id); 
        void Add(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Delete(int id);
    } 

    /// <summary>
    /// The EF-dependent, generic repository for data access
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of entity for this Repository.</typeparam>
    public class MyRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        public MyRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            if (dbContext == null) 
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Null DbContext");
            DbContext = dbContext;
            DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
        }

        protected DbContext DbContext { get; set; }

        protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return DbSet;
        }

        public virtual T GetById(int id)
        {           
            return DbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
            if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
            {
                dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
            }
            else
            {
                DbSet.Add(entity);
            }
        }

        public virtual void Update(T entity)
        {
            DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
            if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                DbSet.Attach(entity);
            }  
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
            if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }
            else
            {
                DbSet.Attach(entity);
                DbSet.Remove(entity);
            }
        }

        public virtual void Delete(int id)
        {
            var entity = GetById(id);
            if (entity == null) return; // not found; assume already deleted.
            Delete(entity);
        }
    }
```

In its constructor, I read this:

```
DbContext = dbContext;
DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
```

Probably it means something but it doesn't make sense to me because `DbContext` is of a type not a variable storing a reference to an object. I always inherit from `DbContext` and create my own `DbContext` and then create an instance / element of it. Does it have any special meaning here? I am wondering why the author did not write these line in this way:

```
MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext();
```

etc.

Thanks

Comment: The repository code you have posted will not compile, it makes more sense if the class actually has the properties that are being assigned in the constructor as in the linked article.

Comment: I've added the interface and the whole class definition but there's more code than that and I am not certain what else is needed. Feel free to make further changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look further down the source code for that class and you will see:

```
protected DbContext DbContext { get; set; }
```

That's declaring a property of type `DbContext` which is also called `DbContext`. When you assign in the ctor, you are assigning to this property.

(The way that the scoping rules work in C# means that within the constructor itself, the `DbContext` resolves to the class's property of that name, not the type `DbContext`.)

Yes, it can be confusing. For this reason, it might have been better for the author to give the property a different name from its type - but this kind of naming is actually fairly common.

At the very least, the ctor should be rewritten thus:

```
public MyRepository(DbContext dbContext)
{
    if (dbContext == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Null DbContext");
    this.DbContext = dbContext;
    this.DbSet = this.DbContext.Set<T>();
}
```